# Free feed reader for Android which allows editing of feeds

Tags: android, open-source, feed-reader

I'm looking for a feed reader for Android with the following characteristics:

1. Should be free software (also misleadingly known as open-source software)
2. Should allow editing feeds (for example changing the URL or removing the feed)

I tried all feed readers from F-Droid (keyword: "rss"), but none satisfies point 2.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you suggesting that most of these do not allow for removing feeds?? Because if they do, 'editing' can be done by copy/paste to editor/edit/copy/paste new.

Comment: I'm new to the Android platform, so perhaps it's my fault. But I haven't been able to edit or remove feeds with any of the apps I tried.

Comment: For most FeedReaders I've seen, long-pressing on the feed pops up a context menu where you can edit details (e.g. disable auto-refresh, manually refresh, remove the feed, put it to a group, edit the URL). Have you tried that? Other apps might have that at a different place. I could e.g. imagine the "overflow menu" (or menu-key) while the feed is open. Tried that? I've not yet encountered any RSS reader where I wasn't able to delete feeds manually.

Comment: Ans PS: "free software (also misleadingly known as open-source software)": Are you looking for *free* software (free as in "free beer"; the correct tag for that is `gratis` here) – or "open-source"? And do you know the difference? To put that into other words: "Must be a fruit (also misleadingly known as cherry)": A cherry is always a fruit, but a fruit not always a cherry ;)

Comment: Free software != Freeware. Free software as in freedom, not price. You should watch some Richard Stallman talks :) The open source camp has different principles. They emphatize practical goals (for example code quality) as opposed to ethical values (freedom). Having source code is not enough. You should also be able to run the program for any purpose, modify it, distribute it to anyone and distribute modifications to anyone, as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed lzzy's suggestion and long-pressed feeds for several seconds.

Results:

- Sparse RSS and SpaRSS allow both editing a feed URL and deleting it
- Flym allows both editing a feed URL and deleting it.*
- FeedHive and Simple RSS don't allow editing or deleting feeds

All the previous apps are free software and are available from F-Droid.

- Delete is a bit hard to find in flym. To delete in flym use the "pencil" icon to open the feed list. Use the slider icon on a feed to move its position in the list or press on the feed name to open a context menu with delete (trash icon).

Answer (score 0):

You can try RSS Reader Xoonity on the [Playstore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.xoonity.OpenRssReader2015)

There are many other features:

- A feature allows you to search for linked articles
- The integration of reading aloud, the application can read your news. For example if you are busy, walking or otherwise, you can
  listen to your news.
- And more.

Comment: As you have done in [your other answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/38089/60), please also state here in this answer (→ [edit]) that you are part of the team that makes this app.

Comment: There is no secret about this. Did you see my signature? This is very explicit "Xoonity".

Comment: If I wanted to hide it, I will take an account without "Xoonity". Which is not my case. 
Nevertheless I came across this post by chance and it seemed to me that this reader met your expectations. If that's not the case, I'm sorry.

Comment: It’s perfectly fine to answer if you are somehow affiliated with the software, you just have to disclose this. This should be done in the answer, because a) user names can be changed (AFAIK there is no history/log), and b) not all users read user names. The note which you added to your other answer ("I'm part of the team that handles this app") would be sufficient.

Comment: Is Xoonity free software (as in freedom)? I haven't find a link to the source code or to the license.